# dynamic input to php mail not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

From dynamic html form, I submit the social net work user login ids. This works fine  but for multiple entries, it is not giving the data input made. The code given below (jquery & form):

```
<form method="post" action="xyz.com.php">
NAME: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" size="28" name="name" /> <br/>
PLACE: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" size="28" name="place"> <br/>
MOBILE:&nbsp;<input type="text" size="28" name="mobile"> <br/><br/>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
   NET_WORK  &nbsp; &nbsp;USER_LOGIN&nbsp; &nbsp;PASS_WORD

<input type="submit" name='submit'  onclick="show_confirm()" value="SUBMIT">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="CLEAR"> 
</form>
```

The PHP Code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

//Email body
$email_body = 
"Name:  $name\n".
"Place: $place\n".
"Mobile:$mobile\n\n".

"Social_net work name:  $net_work\n".
"User_id: $user_login  Pass word: $pass_word\n\n";

//Email sending to
 // code goes here
?>
```

Can any body help me in getting the correct code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `<input type="text" name="net_work[]" /><input type="text" name="user_login[]" /><input type="text" name="pass_word[]" />` and then on PHP side, you can iterate over the data.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

$net_work = $_POST['net_work'];
$user_login = $_POST['user_login'];
$pass_word = $_POST['pass_word'];

$email_body = "Name:  $name\n".
              "Place: $place\n".
              "Mobile:$mobile\n\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($net_work); $i++) {
    $email_body .= "Social_net work name: " . $net_work[$i] . "\n".
                   "User_id: " . $user_login[$i] . "  Pass word: " . $pass_word[$i] . "\n\n";
}
```

And don't forget to sanitize your input!